# Check if HTML5 <dialog> is open

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to check if a `<dialog>` is open using javascript? For example using `dialogId.isOpen()` function ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [HTMLDialogElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement) has the property `open`, which is a boolean whether the dialog is open or not.

I haven't tested, this, but I would assume you can do:

```
if (dialogId.open) {
  // do something
} else {
  // dialog is closed
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `.open` property.

```js
if (dialogElement.open) {
  // ...
}
```

More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/open

Answer (score 1):

You can add an ID to the dialog and access it's open value using DOM like:

```
<dialog id="myDialog">This is an open dialog window</dialog>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  console.log(document.getElementById("myDialog").open);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement/open), but it is still experimental.

Comment: can you propose some css ? this would make your answer stand out above all others

Comment: You can use `dialog[open]` CSS to match for open dialog elements. However, I don't know why you would need to do that since presumably it wouldn't even be displayed if it's not open.

Comment: I was wrong to assume, CSS will help detect this. This was pointless.

Answer (score -1):

I generally use a jQuery UI dialog.

```
$('#dialog').dialog('isOpen')
```

Comment: The question is not about jQuery.

Comment: the description says the code needs to be javascript